# Is there a way to assign different jobs (processes) to specific core in linux using python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing

I have python functions that should run parallelly in a linux environment utilizing multi cores. Is there a way to specify which core should be used for each process explicitly?

Currently, I am using python multiprocessing module to run these python functions as parallel processes in 4 cores.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def hello(name, msg):
    try:
        print("Hello {}".format(name))
        print(msg)
        return true
    except Exception:
        return False

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

msg = "It's a holiday!"
name_list = ["A", "B", "C"]

hello_status = pool.starmap(hello,[(name, msg) for name in name_list])

print(hello_status)
```

Comment: Is there some specific reason you want to run your function on given CPU cores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly with the combination of `os.sched_setaffinity` and `os.sched_getaffinity`. The docstring says:

> Signature: os.sched_setaffinity(pid, mask, /)
>
> Docstring:
>
> Set the CPU affinity of the process identified by pid to mask.
>
> mask should be an iterable of integers identifying CPUs.
>
> Type:      builtin_function_or_method

I couldn't find Python specific documentation, but [these man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) should be a good first source of information.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to look into the `multiprocessing` module and cook up a working example. I came up with two ways to do it using `multiprocessing.Pool` class. First method is by passing an `initializer` argument to the `Pool` constructor call. The second is by using a `Pool.map` function.

```py
import os
from itertools import cycle
import multiprocessing as mp

def _myinit():
    my_pid = os.getpid()
    old_aff = os.sched_getaffinity(0)
    os.sched_setaffinity(0, [0, 3])
    new_aff = os.sched_getaffinity(0)
    print("My pid is {} and my old aff was {}, my new aff is {}".format(my_pid, old_aff, new_aff))
    
def map_hack(AFF):
    my_pid = os.getpid()
    old_aff = os.sched_getaffinity(0)
    os.sched_setaffinity(0, AFF)
    return (my_pid, old_aff, os.sched_getaffinity(0))

PROCESSES = os.cpu_count()

# just an example iterable you could use for the map_hack
# elements of cpus must be iterables, because of os.sched_setaffinity
_mycpus = cycle(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
cpus = [[next(_mycpus)] for x in range(PROCESSES)]

# Since Python 3.3 context managers are supported for mp.Pool

# using initializer argument to change affinity
with mp.Pool(processes=PROCESSES, initializer=_myinit) as pool:

    # do something conditional on your affinity 

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("")

# using mp.Pool.map hack to change affinity
with mp.Pool(processes=PROCESSES) as pool:
    for x in pool.map(map_hack, cpus, chunksize=1):
        print("My pid is {} and my old aff was {}, my new aff is {}".format(*x))

    # do something conditional on your affinity 

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Notice that using `initializer` I hardcoded the affinity of all processes for the first and forth CPUs (0, 3), but that's just because I found it a bit trickier to use `cycle` like I did with `map_hack`. I also wanted to demonstrate that you can set the affinity for any (legal) number of cpus.

I suggest you to through the code and make sure to understand it by reading the relevant docs and playing with it by changing some parameters. It should go without saying that all the `print` statements are only there for us to convince ourselves that the methods are working.

Finally, if you're after more control I'd suggest you to use `mp.Process` objects instead of `mp.Pool`. The same tools from `os` should come in handy there as well.

**WINDOWS:**

This will not work if you're using Windows. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity):

> These functions control how a process is allocated CPU time by the operating system. They are only available on some Unix platforms. For more detailed information, consult your Unix manpages.

In this case you could look into `win32process`, specifically `win32process.SetProcessAffinityMask` and `win32process.GetProcessAffinityMask`, see [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process.html).